# Postgres select using lateral

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I'm after running a query with a subquery (perhaps inefficient) that using a regular expression pattern it can return how many instances of a characters are included with a given record.

In doing so, I came across something like:

```
SELECT t."page",
            product_tree_length,
           Count(*), 
  FROM     "Table" t
  ,
  LATERAL (SELECT (LENGTH((regexp_matches(t."page", '^.+\/c\/(.+?)(?=\/\?|\?|\/$).*$', 'g'))[1]) - LENGTH(REPLACE(((regexp_matches(t."page", '^.+\/c\/(.+?)(?=\/\?|\?|\/$).*$', 'g'))[1]),'/','')))) AS "product_tree_length"
  where t.page like '%\/c/%'
  GROUP BY 1, product_tree_length;
```

However, in selecting the product_tree_length in the main query, the returned data type is a record and not an integer as expected.
If I try to cast the value, PostgreSQL raise an exception that the operation cannot be completed.

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Please show us the complete query ([edit] your question, do not post code in comments)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name query added above. Not sure if it really helps but worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `product_tree_length` is a **table** alias, not a column alias. So if you use that alias in the SELECT list, obviously you get a record.

You have two options to properly define an alias for the *column*

Solution one: use a column alias inside the derived table:

```
select t.page
       product_tree_length.len,
       count(*)
from "Table" t
  cross join lateral (
     SELECT length(....) as len
  ) AS product_tree_length
...
```

Solution two: define a column alias as part of the table alias:

```
select t.page
       product_tree_length.len,
       count(*)
from "Table" t
  cross join lateral (
     SELECT length(....)
  ) AS product_tree_length(len)
...
```

Comment: Thanks. Any advice on which is the best in term of performance?

Comment: There is no difference in performance.

Comment: Thanks, your help was very appreciated. One more question. I noticed you used the CROSS JOIN as opposed me doing the FROM TABLE, LATERAL ... was that a mistake?
Sorry to ask, but PostgreSQL is not my primary database.

Comment: `from a,b` is the same as `from a cross join b` - I prefer the explicit use of CROSS JOIN to document that this is indeed what I intended. The cross join resulting from `from a,b` could have been an accident. (the use of `lateral` doesn't really change that)

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t."page",
       Count(*), 
       (LENGTH((regexp_matches(t."page", '^.+\/c\/(.+?)(?=\/\?|\?|\/$).*$', 'g'))[1]) - LENGTH(REPLACE(((regexp_matches(t."page", '^.+\/c\/(.+?)(?=\/\?|\?|\/$).*$', 'g'))[1]),'/',''))) as product_tree_length  FROM     "Table" t   where t.page like '%\/c/%'   GROUP BY 1,3;
```

I think you don't need a lateral join here if you just wanted the length